# write values in a .txt file in C#

Tags: c#

I m new to programming and i m looking for source code which can write and add values to a text file using C# programming. The code should ask the user to input values in the console window. the values are :- 
Enter Name, Enter account no., Enter Balance

the output should get stored in the text file in the following format :-

```
Mark,10001,230000

Steve,10002,32987

Bruce,10003,23454

William,10004,23454
```

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Generally, it's best to post some code that you've tried for people to look at.

Comment: Here is a kickstart http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8bh11f1k.aspx

Comment: @Prix I was just going to post that.

Comment: @davids some one even made that an answer for faster points lol.

Comment: Google and MSDN documentation is a fantastic resource for very basic questions like this.

Comment: Don't forget to check [`Console.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx) and [`Console.ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) as they will play an important role to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string name;
int number1,number2;
// Read name, number1, number2 from Console
//.....
//.....

//Saving in a file:
string outputFileName = @"c:\myfile.txt"
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputFileName);
sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}",name,number1,number2));
sw.Close();
```

Comment: I really like this answer... Still requiring the user to fill in the blanks, but a useful indication of direction...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. i will try to code the according to your instructions.

Comment: thanks the code is working and i m getting the desired output.